# What movie between 1970-1989 involves computer attacks?

Tags: identify-this-movie

What is the name of the movie (between 1970-1989) that involved programming/reprogramming/hacking computers to trigger or stop a (probably global?) war?

I'm not sure whether the name of the movie contains "Battle" or "Wars".

It also has a kid who was pretty smart, who probably discovered how to hack the computers to trigger (or stop) the war.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Is it [WarGames](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086567/)?

It falls in your 20 year window (1983) and contains the word "war." A "global" war. It also featured a smart hacker kid, played by Matthew Broderick, who inadvertently starts a possible world war.

[image]

He must "teach" the computer that it is not possible to win a global thermonuclear war. This is accomplished by getting it to run through variations of Tic-Tac-Toe, introducing the computer to a no-win scenario. The computer (named Joshua) figures it out and the world is not destroyed.

[image]

The trailer can be viewed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAcEzhQ7oqA).

Comment: Coincidentally there was a nice reference to it in the recent *Winter Soldier*.

Comment: > It also featured a smart hacker kid, played by Matthew Broderick, who inadvertently starts a possible world war. Can't be that smart then ;)

Comment: What's really awesome is Joshua's programmer doesn't care at all the world is saved. He's just impressed that his computer learned something.

Comment: Great movie!  If you're looking for more like it, I always thought [The Manhattan Project](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091472/) with John Lithgow was an underrated film with a similar feel to WarGames.

Comment: What's also very impressive about this movie is that the hacking is actually very realistic. The kid spends days guessing passwords until he gets it. No funky looking GUI app with a progress bar that says "HAXXING PA$$W0RD"

Comment: System Down: Yeah, I was the Computer guy at the beginning of that picture, when it was at Universal, before they threw us out. I showed the Producer how hard it was to guess a password. She didn't understand the concept. (1980) The Atari 800 we used to demo the concept had a 4 voice oscillator. We could actually do the DTMF of the 'war dialing' shown in the movie. They wouldn't let me write the code to do that. There were no computer games then. (Maybe 10? Scott somebody with text adventure games and Missile Command) The Universal Studios guy had a Kojack board game. That's what studios knew